# Kendo Sortable (two columns): Issues moving panels

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, sortables

Here's my working code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/9a8sxw9z/

Here's the Kendo Sortable initiator:

```
$(".panels").kendoSortable({
    filter: ".panel",
    cursor: "move",
    change: function () {

    },
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone()
        .css({ "opacity": 0.8, });
    },
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone()
        .css({ "border": "1px solid #a2a2a2" })
        .height(element.height())
        .width(element.width());
    }
});
```

I'm having a few issues:

1. When I move all of the panels from out of a column, I cannot move any panels back into the empty column
2. In some rare cases, I can't move certain panels. (One scenario I can reproduce is moving "Panel 1" from the left column to the top of the right column. Even though the panel placeholder shows, the panel always reverts back to its original position.)
3. When I have "Panel 1" in the left column and the other three panels in the right, in order to be able to drop a panel underneath the "Panel 1" I need to first drag it over "Panel 1" to trigger this functionality. Ideally, I'd like to be able to drag it underneath and drop it there.

Any idea why these things might be happening? Are there any CSS changes that I could make to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this issue is two-fold:

1. Initializing two instances of the `Sortable` widget and connecting them via the `connectWith` option
2. Adding a `min-height` to the columns, so that you can add panels to empty columns.

Big props to @OnaBai for helping to solve this. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/m72f5z6h/

Answer (score 2):

The explanation to your problems is because a *possible* optimization in Kendo UI Sortable implementation. When you define a Sortable, it creates a list with all the elements that are sortable. When you try to drop an element in the same ordering position, it rejects the movement. I.e. If you try to move the last element of the first column into the first position of the second column, KendoUI computes that `oldIndex` and `newIndex` are the same since there is no change, it rejects the movement.

`Sortable` is for sorting, not for drag and drop. When you move an element between columns you are not sorting but dragging and dropping. In your case, it is true that there is a big visual difference between being last in one column or first in another but that if you think in terms of indexes and arrays is not relevant.

When you have an empty column the question is that dropping area needs to be a `panel` (what you are filtering for). Being empty, there is no valid area where to drop it.

You should consider using `Draggable` and `DropTargetArea` and `DropTarget`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @OnaBai. I remembered another option `connectWith`. I've implemented it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/d7cp2d4y/. This takes care of #2. I'll see what I can do about #1 and 3. I was looking to use `Sortable` because of this demo:http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/sortable-panels. In the demo, it seems like they've got #1 and #3 solved. I'll take a deeper look into that tomorrow.

Comment: In KendoUI Demo, they have two KendoSortable, one for each column. That's why they can move from one to another. Same happens with your JSFiddle in the comment: it works for me. If you add a min-height (so the container does not get empty when moving the last) then it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/d7cp2d4y/1/